# Sentiment Analysis on Google Dataproc with Spark

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis, google-cloud-dataproc

As I am going to perform a spark job for **sentiment** **analysis** on Google Cloud platform and I decided to use **Dataproc**. Is it worth doing with Dataproc or are there any suggestions. I need to perform sentiment analysis for huge dataset from twitter. That is I decided to use the Google cloud platform as my big data and distributed environment.

Answer (score 1):

GCP Dataproc is definitely a great choice for your use-case. Dataproc natively supports Spark and also recently added support for Spark 3.

Please check which [Dataproc image](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/overview) is right for your use case.

Following resources could be helpful while configuring and running Spark job on a cluster.

1. [Creating and configuring cluster](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/create-cluster)
2. [Submit a job](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job)
3. [Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/spark-scala) to run Spark scala job
4. Some more resources from community [Spark job](https://maelfabien.github.io/bigdata/gcps_5/#), [PySpark Job](https://aihub.cloud.google.com/u/0/p/products%2Fc6fd23e0-e9c1-4c31-b4b1-34514f980dd5),

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check this out.